# newbie, contract member balance without specific amount

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm just learning about coding in general, and fighting my way through an Ethereum course.

I've seen the answers about the "contract member balance is deprecated" issue, but I'm just trying to use it in the following:
function GetMyContractBalance() public constant returns (uint) {
       return this.balance;

I added:

```
address myAddress = this;
```

but how do I construct it just using that return function?  I've tried:

```
require (return (this).balance);
require return (this).balance;
return (this).balance;
```

aaaannnnddd - I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but possibly something here will help.

`this.balance` was okay when contracts were directly convertible to addresses. Since `<address>.balance` is the key, things like `0x1234...balance` and `msg.sender.balance` work as expected. `this.balance` was working without issue, but more recent compilers want an explicit conversion from type `contract` to type `address`.

So convert `this` (contract) to an `address` with `address(this)`.

Then you can go `address(this).balance`.

As a one-liner:

```
return address(this).balance;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was it!!!  Thanks so much for the both the answer and the explanation - it makes complete sense.